# Color coded world map with ggplot2 and geom_map

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a world map where the color of each country depends on the value of a variable in the dataframe.

```
> affiliation
# A tibble: 252 × 2
                 region value
                  <chr> <dbl>
1                 Aruba     0
2           Afghanistan     0
3                Angola     0
4              Anguilla     0
5               Albania     0
6               Finland     1
7               Andorra     0
8  United Arab Emirates     0
9             Argentina     2
10              Armenia     0
# ... with 242 more rows
```

The code I have works fine:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

ggplot(affiliation, aes(map_id = region)) + 
    geom_map(aes(fill = value), map = worldMap, color='grey', size=0.3) + 
    expand_limits(x = worldMap$long, y = worldMap$lat) +
    theme_few()+
    theme(legend.position = "bottom",
         axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
         axis.title = element_blank(), 
         axis.text =  element_blank()) +
    scale_fill_gradient(low="white", high="darkblue", name="Number of Affiliates") +
    guides(fill = guide_colorbar(barwidth = 10, barheight = .5))
```

My problem is that most of the values are 0, 1 or 2, very few values in the 20-30 but 1 outlier country has a value in the 330. This makes the color scale useless because that country is shown saturated in color whereas all the countries with much lower values appear white.

I tried to replace `geom_map(aes(fill = value),…` with `geom_map(aes(fill = log(value)),…` but in this case the scale in the legend shows 0 to 5+ (instead of 0 to 330).

What can I do to better control the color saturation of the many countries that have low values in order to make them more visible on the world map ?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the continuous `scale` functions in ggplot2 accept a `trans` argument, which specifies the transformation to use on that aesthetic. This will automatically handle the transformation and labelling.

In your example, adding `trans = "log1p"` (not just `"log"` because your data has a couple `0` values) to the arguments to `scale_gradient_n` could help.

Comment: Great step forward. Thank you. How can I modify the legend so that it shows 0 to 330 range rather than 1 to 5 ?

Comment: You can use the `breaks` argument.  So, if you want to use the colors from @jdobres' answer: `scale_fill_gradientn(name="Number of Affiliates", trans = 'log1p', colours = c('#ff0000', '#cccccc', '#0000ff'), values = c(0, 30, 331) / 331, breaks = c(0, 30, 331))`

Comment: got it. It takes only including the `breaks` and `labels` arguments into the `scale_fill_gradient`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `scale_fill_gradient`, why not try a call to `scale_fill_gradientn`, setting color stops as needed. For example:

```
scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c('#ff0000', '#cccccc', '#0000ff'), values = c(0, 30, 331))
```

Comment: Thank you. I didnt know the `scale_fill_gradientn` . This would be idea if I could provide ranges in the `values` argument but I cant find any info. Is it possible ?

Comment: You can get close by providing extra stops. For instance, `values = c(0, 30, 35, 320, 331), colours = c('red', 'red', 'red', 'green', 'green')`